# Show a string of images if present or default image if field empty

Tags: php, mysql, select, if-statement

As always I'm having trouble with my PHP :( I'm still really new to this, I hope it gets easier eventually...

This is giving me a real headache, hope someone can help.

I'm trying to pull a string of images from a database column. If the images are present, they will be displayed, else default 'no-image' images are displayed in the same format.

Not even sure if I'm going about this completely right. Can you have more than one value in a database column/row? is this an array?

Here is my code so far...

```
$images_array = "SELECT images FROM properties WHERE property = '".$property."' "; // set images query 
$images = mysql_query($images_array); // run images_array query save as images
$images_count = mysql_num_rows($images);
if ($images_count > 0) {
while ($image = mysql_fetch_array($images)) {
echo'<div id="property_images">
<div id="property_main_image"><img alt="Property Image" src="./images/properties/'.$image['images'].'" /></div>
<div id="property_sub_image"><img alt="Property Image" src="./images/properties/'.$image['images'].'" /></div>
<div id="property_sub_image"><img alt="Property Image" src="./images/properties/'.$image['images'].'" /></div>
</div>';
}
} else {
echo'<div id="property_images">
<div id="property_main_image"><img alt="No Property Image" src="./images/properties/no_image" /></div>
<div id="property_sub_image"><img alt="No Property Image" src="./images/properties/no_image" /></div>
<div id="property_sub_image"><img alt="No Property Image" src="./images/properties/no_image" /></div>
</div>';
}
```

It is displaying the images correctly, when they are present in the database, otherwise the alt="Property Image" is being displayed. Which is leading me to think the code always sees $images as TRUE... ??

Can I show multiple images in this way, by saving multiple file names is the same MySQL value and fetching the array/string ???

Thanks in advance for any help :)

As requested the structure of my database...

```
| properties
| ID | address | area | postcode | phone | mobile | tenancy | type | available | deposit | rent | description | bedrooms | bathrooms | communal | kitchens | parking | garden | broadband | property | vacancy | images |
```

Comment: Could you show us the structure in your properties table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$image` variable always returns TRUE when you execute the query.

So my advise is to do the following:

```
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($count > 0 ) {
....
}
```

UPDATED:

```
$images = mysql_query($images_array); // run images_array query save as images
$images_count = mysql_num_rows($images);

while ($image = mysql_fetch_array($images)) {
    $lettercount = strlen(str_replace(' ', '', $images));
    if($lettercount > 0) {
        /* show the images */
    }else{
        /* show the default images */
    }
}
```

UPDATED 2:

```
$images_array = "SELECT * FROM properties WHERE property = '".$property."' "; // set images query 
$images = mysql_query($images_array); // run images_array query save as images

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($images)) { 
        $check_string_lenght = strlen(str_replace(' ', '', $row['images']));
    if($check_string_lenght > 0) {
    /* or if($row['images'] != '') { */
       echo'<div id="property_images">
       <div id="property_main_image"><img alt="Property Image" src="./images/properties/'.$row['images'].'" /></div>
       <div id="property_sub_image"><img alt="Property Image" src="./images/properties/'.$row['images'].'" /></div>
       <div id="property_sub_image"><img alt="Property Image" src="./images/properties/'.$row['images'].'" /></div>
       </div>';
} else {
       echo'<div id="property_images">
       <div id="property_main_image"><img alt="No Property Image" src="./images/properties/no_image" /></div>
       <div id="property_sub_image"><img alt="No Property Image" src="./images/properties/no_image" /></div>
       <div id="property_sub_image"><img alt="No Property Image" src="./images/properties/no_image" /></div>
       </div>';
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have edited to the above code. But I'm still getting the same issue (images load if present, wrong alt text if images not present) @Diego Pucci

Comment: That's strange, can you provide your HTML output please?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still new to this, what do you mean by my HTML output? @Diego Pucci

Comment: Well when you run your PHP file your echo statement will output the HTML. I need to see what's the actual HTML output your code gives after having being processed

Comment: I get the `<img alt="Property Image">` values displayed three times as "Property Image" in the three `<div>`s in their styled positions.

Comment: .. because there is no image in the relevant database field, it is showing the alt values which is fine, but it is showing the wrong alt values.

Comment: I am more interested in the src="" parameter. What do you get there? Just an empty space?

Comment: if there is a result in the database ... The above `while (mysql_fetch_array(images)) {` displays three images. Whereas if there is no result in the database .. the alt code `Property Image` is being displayed three times (for each `<img>`)

Comment: Yes but since you have this src="./images/properties/'.$image['images'].'" I am assuming that $image['images'] is not returning anything so you only have this src="./images/properties/" in your HTML output. Am I right? Is this what happening? Anyway try my updated code

Comment: Right, yes I understand now :) Yes it's returning `src="./images/properties/"` when it can't find a result in the database. I have updated to your new code, and I'm afraid it's still doing the same thing. Returning `src="./images/properties/"` and displaying the `alt="Property Image"` I only want it to execute `src="./images/properties/'.$image['images'].'"` if there is a value in the database.

Comment: That's strange. The first code actually check if there is a result in the DB and the second code check if there is a result the lenght of it just to avoid empty results..So there must be something else. Lastly try my last update. But I am not sure it will do exactly what you need but maybe let you fix the issue. Let me know if it works this time :D

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!! What ever you did seemed to work :D I'm not sure how/why, but thank you! Any ideas how i could pull multiple/different images? would it be easier to save them in seperate columns? Thanks again :)

Comment: For sure it is easier to pull them in different columns rather than pulling them into an array. Also as a mysql convention you should always have only one value for each column.

Answer (score 1):

```
define('NO_IMAGE', '/path/to/no/img'); // path to "noimage" image
$images_array = "SELECT CASE WHEN images IS NULL or images = '' THEN '".NO_IMAGE."' ELSE images END FROM properties WHERE property = '".$property."' ";
```

If images field value is null or empty string, then images value = NO_IMAGE value, else available value.

Comment: You should add more to your answer, explaining a little bit.